# Object is not iterable even though i return 2 variables?

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

I call a class called Login_window with two variables "equaling" it ( wasnt sure how to word that but you'll see in the code) and when this line runs an error occurs: "TypeError: 'Login_window' object is not iterable". Although this error appears the entry window still appears how its meant and i can print of the entry if i dont have Login_window "equal" two variables.

Heres the code that goes wrong ( i didnt include alot of it because the rest works and is not needed ):

```
class Login_window():
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title("Login")

        top_frame = LabelFrame(self.window)
        top_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

        mid_frame = LabelFrame(self.window)
        mid_frame.grid(row=2,column=0)

        bottom_frame= LabelFrame(self.window)
        bottom_frame.grid(row=3,column=0)
        Label(top_frame,text = "Enter username:").grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.username_entry = Entry(top_frame)
        self.username_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        Label(mid_frame,text = "Enter password:").grid(row=3,column=0)
        self.password_entry = Entry(mid_frame)
        self.password_entry.grid(row = 3,column = 3)

        ttk.Button(bottom_frame , text = 'Enter',command = self.returN).grid(row=4,column=0)

    def returN(self):
        username=self.username_entry.get()
        password=self.password_entry.get()
        return username,password


def start():
    window=Tk()
    username,password=Login_window(window)
    return username,password
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Login_window(window)` does **not** call `returN`

Answer (score 0):

Your `start()` function is not working properly, as below:

```
def start():
    window=Tk()
    username,password = Login_window(window)
    return username,password
    window.mainloop()
```

Firstly, you cannot execute the code `window.mainloop()` after the function returns.

Secondly, your `Login_window` class cannot be assigned to two variables like you have done. That what the "not itterable" error means. You would need a tuple with two values to do that. For example: `username, password = ("my_username", "my_password")`

Yours is a custom object so if you want two variables to be set to it, do it on two lines:

username = Login_window(window)
password = Login_window(window)

Note that this does not make sense either, as you only have one window (equal to `Tk()`) so why do you need to reference it twice? Also, it is not clear why variables like username and password should be equal to a window object rather than just strings.

Finally, the `return(self)` method looks like it should be part of your class, but the indentation means that it is not.

We would need more information on what you are trying to achieve in order to help you.

Comment: heres the main code where its called, i cant include all of it because its 3000 
    `charactersish:def Login():
        import tkinter3
        data = tkinter3.start()
        entered_user_name=data[0]
    entered_user_password=data[1]
        validation=db.UP_validation(entered_user_name,entered_user_password)
        if validation == None or validation == "Username or Password INCORRECT":
           print("\nUsername or Password INCORRECT\n")
        else:
            print(validation)`

Comment: What im actually trying to do is to return the username and password from the two different entry boxes to the original code where the tkinter file was imported. Im literally new this day to tkinter so i dont really have any clue, i did search google for an answer but i couldnt find anything. Was reluctant to post this on here but i really need to figure this out ( or for someone else to do it for me ;/ )